# Where does Kolmogorov stand among the pantheon of mathematicians?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, soft-question, math-history

Kind of a soft question. More out of historical curiosity than really seeking an affirmative answer.

Reading up a little bit, over time, I am increasingly tempted to believe that, the Soviet mathematician Andrey Kolmogorov is not celebrated as much as an equivalent European or American genius of similar calibre. His contribution to modern science, including probability theory and computational complexity are not often talked about as much in the mainstream. Is this a mere coincidence or just that his work missed the visibility aspect, because of the geo political situation of the 20th century? Isn't  Kolmogorov, one of the top 3 applied mathematician of 20th century?

Comment: Perhaps it would be slightly exaggerated to say that many who study probability theory kneel in reverent prayer to Kolmogorov daily. But it is not exaggerated to say that many think that Kolmogorov showed that probability theory _is_ (sic: _is_) the study of functions whose domain is a measurable space of total measure $1,$ with various conventions established earlier by Lebesgue. They ought to hold instead that Kolmogorov showed that that is a very useful way of looking at probability theory in many contexts. $\qquad$

Comment: It's hard to see outside my mathematician perspective where 'of course everyone knows Kolmogorov was one of the most important mathematicians of the twentieth century'. What makes a mathematician famous in the mainstream is an odd thing. Turing is (probably) a household name, but Church isn't, even though their ideas were of roughly the same importance in the same field. This probably has more to do with the human drama surrounding Turing, as well as the pop-sci-ready concept of the Turing test. (And a major motion picture helps, though I feel like he was pretty mainstream before this.)